# How to remove /year/month from uploaded medias?

Tags: permalinks, database, mysql

I have removed year/month from my media's structure, But still i have a thousand of images using the old structure.

I need to remove the year/month from these published attachments, however i noticed that the metadata saved in the database is serialized and i can't simply use a text editor to replace them.

There is a plugin called `Better search & replace` that considers serialized data while changing the database.

Is it enough to just replace the URLs from for example `2016/10/` to empty in order to remove it (in `wp_postmeta`)? or i have to do it in other tables too?

I copied all my images to a single folder and i'm sure i don't have duplicate filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i checked the database and noticed that every date is stored in a format like `2016-07-11`. i did not found any date like `2016/07/11` but maybe some other plug-ins use it but none of my plug-ins use it

every date like `2016/07/11` was in the link so i think you can do it by search replace but be careful and have a backup of your database

also don't change guids they are needed for `rss reader`